# Access origin has been blocked by CORS policy Laravel api and Nuxt.js

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I am trying to develop a simple application using Laravel api and Nuxt.js
Now, `GET`, `DELETE` and `POST` is working perfectly in my Nuxt.js app.
but when i run `PUT` i guess the following error message in console, i test `PUT` command with postman application and it is working perfectly with it.

But in browser with Nuxt.js i got the following error messages in console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/movie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.


actualizar.vue?a2cc:70 Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js?16d0:16:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?ec6c:84:1)



    PUT http://localhost:8000/api/movie net::ERR_FAILED
```

this is my Cors.php archive in laravel with the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    */
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
   {
       return $next($request)
      
  //Url a la que se le dara acceso a las peticiones
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
  //Métodos a los que se da acceso
  ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
  //Headers de la petición
  ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",'*');

   }
}
```

anyhelp to solve this issue?, Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use your backend (Laravel) to handle the API Fetch and then return the response to your javascript.

This is mainly caused by the API provider's CORS rule that bans CORS.

Here's a simple workflow :

1. javascript send request to laravel
2. laravel process the request and send the PUT data to the api
3. laravel returns the response from the api to the javascript